# Morphia Aggregation functions

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm quite new to Morphia. Is there an easy way to make opreations like sum, average, max, min ?

I already saw some "Play" plugin but I'm not sure how it works, and I would like to use plain Morphia.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) feature of MongoDb with Morphia.

Example of using it, you find on github

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/ZipCodeDataSetTest.java

Comment: yes, i saw it also, but it is quite unclear to me. I have only one @Entity, and all i want to do is sum, mean or max min. Aggregationpipleine takes two entitsie, as I understand (or not) and I need only one

Comment: You need to give morphia some type to dump the data in to.  That could be the same as the input type but that'll be pretty rare, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Morphia does support aggregate from 0.110. Even if is not documented, [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationTest.java) you have some test examples